# What is difference between build and archive in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to build a framework, when I compiled the project using build and archive using command line,the result is different about their sizes. "build " is much larger than archive.

why?

The command I use:

`xcodebuild -target xx -configuration Release clean build UFW_ACTION=archive`

`xcodebuild -scheme xx -configuration Release clean archive`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> **Build:** The compilation for your source code to execute the project
>
> **Archive**: As its name says, it is the overall package (that contains .app and other related files). From archive you can create .IPA file similar to .apk file (android) with that you can distribute your application.

Comment: Archive doesn't actually produce an .ipa file but a directory (.xcarchive) containing the .app, the symbols and other informations needed to pubblish to the AppStore. This .xcarchive is used as starting point to generate the .ipa

Answer (score 3):

The archive (`.ipa`) file is a zip file, which will account for the difference in size.