# What is difference between release and debug archive in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

What is difference between release and debug archive in Xcode? is it a difference of creating a build during archive? If yes what is that particular difference?[image]

Though there is a existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240651/what-is-difference-between-build-and-archive-in-xcode) about difference between build and archive in Xcode, but it will be highly appreciated if some will provide some more information about this as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure independent sets of runtime settings in XCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497552/how-to-configure-independent-sets-of-runtime-settings-in-xcode)

Comment: @Vizllx The question mentioned to mark this as a duplication is about different thing and so not cover my question.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2684741?tstart=0

Comment: Can you please elaborate what  this line "a duplication is about different thing"?

Comment: @TM the differences are set up in the build settings. There are plenty or differences(or maybe no differences) based on the values you set up in the build settings. You should take a look at the link Vizllx posted above.

Comment: @iOSAddicted will took a look one more time.